# iOS approach to location based peer to peer communication

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gps, multipeer-connectivity

I recently have been very interested in developing iOS apps (for iPhone specifically) that can **"communicate" with nearby (geographically) apps.** 
 
 
My networking skills/resources are limited, so I was really hoping to make it a **peer to peer** app, avoiding the need to host my own server.
 
 
It seems like I have a few options, including the newish **Multi-peer Connectivity framework, and Location services.**
 
 
I was hoping someone who has experience writing peer to peer apps could direct me to what they think the most logical approach would be.
 
 
Additonal info:
 
*I am only looking to send text/small pictures (speed is not a priority)
 
*Detecting nearby (within a mile or so) geographically is the main goal
 
*Possibly communicate with Android devices (I know multi-peer connectivity lacks this)

Answer (score 1):

Peer-to-peer communication is limited to a range of about 50 meters. To extend the range you can create a mesh using intermediate peers to relay messages. That is how the [Firechat](https://opengarden.com/firechat) app works.

If you want to communicate over greater distances without a mesh I believe you will need to go via the cloud

Answer (score 1):

In terms of communicating with Android, the people who made FireChat are coming out with their SDK.  Not sure how/what pricing will be but I assume they will offer this cross platform function.  There are of course other ways but I am not that advanced in app development to know them yet.

For a simple chat app there are many free online tutorials that help you create iphone to iphone chat app that can also send images.  Range will be limited however to whatever is max for WiFi. Like Keith said, mesh is another option but I believe everyone in the network has to have the app for the data to bounce.